# Twilio send specific message based on message received

Tags: twilio

I was wondering if anyone knows of good resources for learning how to send Twilio messages based on what message a client sends. For example if a client texts "current song", to send the current song title. If a client texts "current artist", to send the current artist. I wasn't able to find anything about that in the Twilio documentation. I may have overlooked it or something. Wasn't sure how to do a Google/Bing search on the topic as I wasn't getting results with my search term.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

For your example, you would want to parse the message body of any incoming SMS and have some logic on your end that checks if that message is "current song" or "current artist" and handle that appropriately. How you handle generating a response is left entirely to the developer's discretion.

To get up and running quickly with receiving and responding to SMS, [check out the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) if you haven't already. The dropdown on the right hand will let you select from several languages to get started with.

A quick example using NodeJS with Express would look like this:

```
router.post('/text',function(req,res) { 
  if(req.body.Body == "current artist"){
    console.log("A request for the current artist has been made.");
  }
});
```